# hay un problema en esta condicional que no funciona!

Tags: javascript, html5

[image: este codigo de la imagen es identico al otro]

[image: este codigo es el mismo, tanto la varible foto1 como fotoPerfil creo que son exactamente lo mismo]
[image: y me da resultado de "falso" esto porque? no comprendo disculpen]

aca hay un problema con esto,ambos elementos son un string con la direccion de una imagen y tienen exactamente lo mismo y en la condicion me sale que es falso? y esto porque? no comprendo

este es el codigo:

Comment: si, es que en codigo no se ve lo que quiero mostrar, que es el resultado, no se ve bien en la imagen? conozco poco de esto disculpen

Answer (score 1):

Ahi estaria, le modifique la consulta y como seteas las variables, agregue un foto2 para la comparacion para que no compares siempre lo mismo y agregue un console.log para mostrar cuando son iguales y cuando distintas. Usando fotoPerfil.length en el for te aseguras de recorrer el largo del array unicamente.
Tene en cuenta que estas usando urls de imagen de un sitio que te las da random, si queres testear con dos imagenes iguales asegurate que no varien.
Saludos

```
let container = document.querySelector('.card-container')
const img = `https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x150?person`
const imgPost = `https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x400?nature`

async function principal(){
    [textos, names] = await Promise.all([
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`),
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    ]);
    let textObj = await textos.json()
    let nameObj = await names.json()

    let html = ''

    let fotoPerfil = await distinto(img)
    let fotoPost = await distinto(imgPost)
    console.log(fotoPerfil)
    console.log(fotoPost)
    let foto1 = fotoPost[0];
    let foto2;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < fotoPerfil.length; i++) {
        let texto = textObj[i].title;
        let name = nameObj[i].name;
        foto2 = fotoPerfil[i]
        
        if (foto1 !== foto2) {
        console.log('son distintas');
            html += `<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
        <img src="${fotoPerfil[i]}" class="fadeIn">
        <h3 class="fadeIn">${name}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-text">
        <p class="fadeIn">${texto}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-post">
        <img src="${fotoPost[i]}" class="fadeIn">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`
        foto1 = fotoPerfil[i]
        

        }else {
            console.log('son iguales')
        }
    }
    container.innerHTML = html
    /* checkBoxes() */
}
principal()



async function distinto(dir){
    let ArrFotos = await Promise.all([fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir)])

    let fotos = []

    ArrFotos.forEach(obj =>{
        fotos.push(obj.url)
    })

    let fotosUnicas = [...new Set(fotos)]

    return fotosUnicas
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seria bueno que pongas el codigo entero para poder entender el tipo de dato que estas sacando del array. Intuyo que el problema es el triple igual que valida que el sea igual pero tambien que el tipo de dato sea el mismo. intenta con

```
if(foto1 == fotoPerfil[i])
```

Si no es eso voy a necesitar ver algo mas del codigo para ayudarte

Comment: ahi agregue otra respuesta con el codigo ya que intente en la misma pregunta y me dio muchas trabas asi que ahi esta, espero se pueda entender

Comment: en realidad la idea del codigo es generar una imagen distinta en cada iteracion del bucle y agregarla al html pero esto no me funciona, ya que me salen muchas imagenes repetidas y no es lo que esperaba

Comment: y ps examinando el codigo me tope con esto en la condicional if, y ya probe con 2 (==) asi como me dijiste e igual

Answer (score 0):

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.card-container')
const img = `https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x150?person`
const imgPost = `https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x400?nature`

async function principal(){
    [textos, names] = await Promise.all([
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`),
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
    ]);
    let textObj = await textos.json()
    let nameObj = await names.json()

    let html = ''

    let fotoPerfil = await distinto(img)
    let fotoPost = await distinto(imgPost)
    console.log(fotoPerfil)
    console.log(fotoPost)
    let foto1;
    let foto2;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let texto = textObj[i].title;
        let name = nameObj[i].name;

        if (foto1 !== fotoPerfil[i]) {
            html += `<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
        <img src="${fotoPerfil[i]}" class="fadeIn">
        <h3 class="fadeIn">${name}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-text">
        <p class="fadeIn">${texto}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-post">
        <img src="${fotoPost[i]}" class="fadeIn">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>`
        foto1 = fotoPerfil[i]
        foto2 = fotoPost[i]

        }else {
            console.log('cualquier cosa')
        }
    }
    container.innerHTML = html
    /* checkBoxes() */
}
principal()



async function distinto(dir){
    let ArrFotos = await Promise.all([fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir), fetch(dir)])

    let fotos = []

    ArrFotos.forEach(obj =>{
        fotos.push(obj.url)
    })

    let fotosUnicas = [...new Set(fotos)]

    return fotosUnicas
}
```

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)